# Configure build path libraries separate from workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have Eclipse running on two different computers. I was able to get away from some of the build path stupidities, like Eclipse wanting to use absolute paths for some jar files, but I'm stuck dealing with Tomcat. I need to reference Tomcat libraries so I have access to servlet related classes. When I copied my workspace from one computer to the other, the absolute paths to the Tomcat libraries were there and were wrong due to Tomcat being installed in a different location.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to reference the local Tomcat libraries without that information ending up in the workspace and therefore in source control? I don't want to be stuck with the previous developers weird directory structure on my computer (she had more than one logical drive so on Windows I would have to create a fake drive letter to deal with the absolute paths).

I also don't want to move the libraries into my workspace because I think that when I deploy to a server, I want my code to use the appropriate servlet classes for that server.

Comment: Ok, so I just used the user libraries feature to add the Tomcat libraries for the local machine. The user libraries configuration is in Windows->Configuration->User Libraries. I then included my user library into the project/workspace. The references to servlet classes don't show any errors. I have yet to see how this works on the other computer but it seems promising.

Comment: If you use the Web Tools, this is mostly handled for you. Are you not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, which I personally use, is [User Libraries](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fbuildpath%2Fref-preferences-user-libraries.htm).

First you create a User Library, with all the Tomcat jar files you want to use:

- `Window` > `Preferences`
- `Java` > `Build Path` > `User Libraries`
- Click `New...`, then give it a name, e.g. `Tomcat Library`
- Select it, then click `Add External JARs...`
- Locate the Tomcat `lib` folder and multi-select all the jar files you want to add to your classpath.

Now add the User Library to your projects class path:

- Right-click project in `Package Explorer`, select `Build Path` > `Add Libraries...`
- Select `User Library`, and click `Next >`
- Select the user library that you just created

The project now know to include the named User Library in the build path.

The *name* of the User Library is part of the source control check-in, but the list of jar files are not. Anybody using this project from source control will have to create the library themselves.

Note: You can export/import the User Library from the dialog where you created it. The exported file is XML. That way you can copy the library definition to another machine where Tomcat is installed in the same folder, or you can edit the XML file, if the change in folder is simple (find/replace).